# Polling Batchwise a Database Table with Reactive extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive

I am trying to figure out ways to Poll a single DB Table using Reactive Extensions.

I have a Method `GetEmployees()`which returns  all Records from Employee table.

```
    var query = "SELECT emp_no, first_name, last_name FROM Employees" ;
    while (reader.Read())
      { :
        :
        yield return employee;
     }
```

Next , I have a Extension method which takes the above Employee Source ( AsObservable ) and Periodically polls the observable and returns Actual  results.

```
 public static IObservable<T> Poll<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan period, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            return Observable.Timer(period, scheduler)
                        .SelectMany(_ => source)    
                        .Retry()
                        .Repeat();  //Loop
        }
```

However when I try to call the above Poll from my client code after periodic interval , I see it repeats the same result over and over again. It doesnt progress to the next batch of records from table .

Client code looks like this :-

```
private static void StreamDBDataWithThrottling()
        {
            var r = GetEmployees().ToObservable();

            r.Poll(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Scheduler.Default)
                //.Take(20)
                // .Concat(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.01)).Take(100))
                .Buffer(20, 20)
                .TakeUntil(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(15))
                .Subscribe((data) =>
                {
                    foreach (var item in data)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.FirstName);
                        // Todo: - Real Business Logic with Task.Factory.StartNew( _ => { // intensive task here } )
                    }
                });
        }
```

The table will Not have new data coming in once processing has started.

I am learning the caveats of Push based collections and Concurrent Collections .

Thanks in advance if you can guide me with -  How to batchwise process all records of the table until the last record.

Comment: I am not sure why you think that creating an observable of an IEnumerable would magically get data from the database and push that data into a stream. Your  `GetEmployees` is called only once, so there is just a one time call to the db. Also, what are you trying to accomplish with this buffering and TakeUntil? Could you describe your desired behavior a bit more?

Comment: The code in your question does not show where the issue is coming from. This isn't a [mcve]. As such we can only guess at what the issue might be. I suspect that you have structured the code so that a subscriber to your observable isn't initiate the call to `GetEmployees`. I think deferred execution is your problem here. I also think you'll need a `Observable.Defer(() => GetEmployees().ToObservable())` somewhere. But without complete, running code that replicates your issue I can't be sure.

Comment: Hi @peter-bons , thanks for reading through my question.   Yes I expected  my GetEmployees() method would yield a "stream of Enumerable" . And my StreamDBDatawithThrorrling() would batch process the yielded stream. I think I am wrong in this assumption. So, now I am implementing a StroredProc which alone sends  batches of  records .. Reactive extension will use to schedule periodic polls to the same StroredProc .   Then my tasks will process the obtained files by spawning tasks for each batch.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, thank you for going thru my question. I have come across few opinions that Reactive programming is the way to go for Async batch processing of Items .  Reactive extension suffice the Task by bringing in Push based collections .  My basic need is to have a Observable collection which acts as a source for spawning Task against periodically obtained resultsets. Poll the DB > obtain batch by batch records > spin up subscribed Tasks against those obtained records.. . I need Retry(), Repeat()  to answer scenarios that can arose like  DB/network to DB  down

Comment: @Manotoshsil - No, you don't need `Retry()`/`Repeat()`. You probably just need `Defer()`. You need to show us your full code - a [mcve] - for us to know exactly what the issue is.